# overload the overloadedFunc() function

Tags: javascript

I need to overload a function overloadedFunc() which takes 3 arguments. For the 1st argument of the function set the default value [1, 2, 3], for the 2nd - the value 2, for the 3rd - the function that returns the product of the first two arguments, and the function can multiply both arrays and numbers.
The overloadedFunc() function returns the result of the default function.
I have a code but it throws an error. How can I solve this problem?

```js
function overloadedFunc(arg1 = [1, 2, 3], arg2 = 2, arg3 = multiply()) {
  const res = multiply(arg1, arg2);
  return res;
}

function multiply(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1.forEach((item) => {
    item * arg2;
  });
}

console.log(overloadedFunc()); // [2, 4, 6]
console.log(overloadedFunc([2, 4, 6], 3)); // [6, 12, 18]
console.log(overloadedFunc(10)); // 20
```

Comment: What is the error? What line does it occur on? If you set a breakpoint on that line, what do you see?

Comment: in "Run code snippet" you can test my code. Error with forEach()

Comment: You are responsible for testing your code, not us. Set a breakpoint other, see why you cannot read the `forEach` property of `undefined`. Look at the stack trace to see why it is undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `arg3 = multiply` (without the call)?

Comment: You will get the same error again once you fix the `arg3` issue when you call `overloadedFunc(10)`, since `10` is a value (and therefor `arg1` doesn't use the default), but does not have a `.forEach()`

Comment: Also, `multiply(arg1, arg2)` should be `arg3(arg1, arg2)`, otherwise there is no point in asking for a 3rd parameter if you call `multiply` regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `overloadedFunc`, you need to take `multiply` as a default (do not invoke the function); and you need to call `arg3`.

You can simplify the `multiply` function to return a mapping.

```js
const multiply = (arr, n) =>
  Array.isArray(arr)
    ? arr.map(x => x * n)
    : arr * n;

const overloadedFunc = (
  arg1 = [1, 2, 3],
  arg2 = 2,
  arg3 = multiply
) =>
  arg3(arg1, arg2);


console.log(overloadedFunc());             // [2, 4, 6]
console.log(overloadedFunc([2, 4, 6], 3)); // [6, 12, 18]
console.log(overloadedFunc(10));           // 20
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This can be re-written to simplify the `arg3` (aka `multiply`) callback.

```js
const multiply = (scalar, multiplier) => scalar * multiplier;

const overloadedFunc = (
  arg1 = [1, 2, 3],
  arg2 = 2,
  arg3 = multiply
) =>
  Array.isArray(arg1)
    ? arg1.map(x => arg3(x, arg2))
    : arg3(arg1, arg2);


console.log(overloadedFunc());             // [2, 4, 6]
console.log(overloadedFunc([2, 4, 6], 3)); // [6, 12, 18]
console.log(overloadedFunc(10));           // 20
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to be able to pass a number like 10 to the overloadedFunc() function, and not like in your example in an array. Is it possible to implement like this?

Comment: @trainee ok, I updated the function to utilize a ternary to evaluate `arg1` as an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

look at the 3rd parameter, you are calling the function `multiply()` without any parameters, if you wanna send the reference use `multiply`

The code will be like this:

```js
// fixing the 3rd parameter 
function overloadedFunc(arg1 = [1, 2, 3], arg2 = 2, arg3 = multiply) {
    const res = multiply(arg1, arg2);
    return res;
}
```

```js
// return the result in multiply function 
function multiply(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1.forEach((item) => {
    item * arg2;
  });   
  return arg1;
}
```

```
// fix the 3rd call to use [10] in array instead of 10 as a number
console.log(overloadedFunc()); // [2, 4, 6]
console.log(overloadedFunc([2, 4, 6], 3)); // [6, 12, 18]
console.log(overloadedFunc([10])); // [20]
```